# Tkinter assign Command to button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am new to tkinter GUI. I was trying below example to assigned command to a button called print. Any Idea where I am going wrong, I get error:

> _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-command": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side

from tkinter import *

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        fm = Frame(master)
        Button(fm, text='Print').pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES, command = self.hello_world)
        Button(fm, text='Center').pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)
        Button(fm, text='Bottom').pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=X, expand=YES)
        Button(fm, text='Left').pack(side=LEFT)
        #Button(fm, text='This is the Center button').pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(fm, text='Right').pack(side=RIGHT)
        fm.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def hello_world(self):
        print ("Hello World")

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.option_add('*font', ('verdana', 12, 'bold'))
root.title("Pack - Example 12")
display = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory - bad option, since `command` is [widget's option](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) (an argument of the `Button` class), not an argument of `pack` method.

Comment: `Button( ..., command=...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error tells you what is wrong with your code. `command` is not a valid option for `pack`(or any other geometry manager). command is an option for widget which means you need to use it while creating an instance of said widget.

```
Button(fm, ..., command=...)
```

<sub><sub>I think there should be an answer instead of answering in comments, that's why I added one.</sub></sub>

Comment: sometimes solution is so simple (and boring or you don't want to write the same explanation 5th time in one day) so it is easier to put short comment than write answer with explanation. And then others can put it as answer adding full explanation.

Comment: @furas I am sorry if my sub-note seemed like something bad. I was just trying to explain myself about why I added an answer long after two correct comments.

Comment: don't worry, your subnote is nice :) And this is why I decided to add explanation why we put solutin in comment instead of in answer :)